# Can Sales force chatter plus license holders view Leads, Opportunities, dashboards and reports?

Tags: chatter, licenses

our company is limited to only 20 full saleforce license and we need an alternative way to give access to our other staff. We don't want them to edit the opportunities but they must be able to see and comment on them.

Answer (score 1):

Chatter Plus licence users cannot view Leads or Opportunities, but can see Reports and Dashboards with content from objects that they can view. [Salesforce Chatter licence overview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_chatter.htm&type=0).

You may be better off with Partner Community licences as these can see Leads and Opportunities as well as Reports and Dashboards. [SF community licence documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=0).